# subtract a set of numbers, displayed as time, to obtain the difference in hours and minutes using excel 2010

Tags: excel

A table of numbers representing time are displayed as 723 and 1700. These would be interpreted to be 7 hours and 23 minutes in the first cell and 17 hours and 0 minutes in the second cell. The different would be 9 hours and 37 minutes.

I tried multiplying all the the numbers by .01 and then converting them to text. I used find and replace to replace all the decimals with colons. I then converted the cells to the time format again and subtracted them. Unfortunately this doesn't work for all values.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming column A is start time, column B is finish time, and the duration you want to calculate is column C, then use this formula in cell C2, format as `h:mm;@` and copy down:

`=INT(LEFT(TEXT(B2,"0000"),2)/24)+TIME(LEFT(TEXT(B2,"0000"),2),RIGHT(B2,2),0)-TIME(LEFT(TEXT(A2,"0000"),2),RIGHT(A2,2),0)`

[image]

Comment: What does "@"  accomplish in the format? I tried it with and without and got the same answer. Also, when the 1700 is replaced with 2400 the answer is not 16:37

Comment: @torisemo Updated formula, verified it works when B2 is set to 2400 now.  As for the "@", it allows for text results instead of number results if preferred.  In the vast majority of cases, there is no practical difference and the "@" can be omitted if preferred.

Comment: Thank you tigeravatar, I really appreciate you taking the time to help me.